# Axios in Nuxt.js is not catch error properly

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

As I mentioned above my Axios on Nuxt.js is not catch error properly

I need to know the error, so I can prompt to let the user know their input is not correct but it only **console.log** the error code status not the message from my API

this is my code

```
await axios
  .post(
    "API LINK",
    {
      email: user.email,
      password: "123456",
      name: user.name,
      dob: user.dob ?? null,
      gender: user.gender ?? null,
      profileImage: imageUrl ?? user.profileImage,
      userType: user.userType
    }
  )
  .then(res => {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('fail');
    console.log(err)
  })
```

This is what log on a chrome console

```
error
add.vue?104b:181 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:61)
```

But what I expect from the **console.log(err)** is

```
(This is response from postman)
{
    "message": "Error creating new user.",
    "error": {
        "code": "auth/invalid-password",
        "message": "The password must be a string with at least 6 characters."
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is happening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
 console.log(err.response)
```

To make the code cleaner you can destructure the argument:

```
  .catch(({ response }) => {
    console.log('fail');
    console.log(response)
  })
```

If you want to use some other property name instead of `response` you can do it like this:

```
  .catch(({ response: err }) => {
    console.log('fail');
    console.log(err)
  })
```

The problem is when the console.log tries to output the error, the string representation is printed, not the object structure, so you do not see the `.response` property.

Here you can read about https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. It's working now. Btw can you explain to me why using err.response not the err because before this project I always use the err only and it work just fine.

Comment: @Purinut The problem is when the console.log tries to output the error, the string representation is printed, not the object structure, so you do not see the .response property. Here you can read about https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960

Answer (score 1):

This is working with a try / catch structure, which is the preferred way

```
  try {
    await axios.post("API LINK", {
      email: user.email,
      password: "123456",
      name: user.name,
      dob: user.dob ?? null,
      gender: user.gender ?? null,
      profileImage: imageUrl ?? user.profileImage,
      userType: user.userType,
    })
    console.log("success", res)
  } catch ({ response }) {
    console.log("fail", response)
  }
```